# Custom Authorization Attribute Not Always Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, filter, authorization

I have taken code from a previous custom Authorization attribute and come up with this:

```
    public class PortalAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private WebSiteSession m_UserSession;
    protected WebSiteSession myUserSession
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_UserSession == null)
                try { m_UserSession = (WebSiteSession)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"]; }
                catch
                {
                    m_UserSession = new WebSiteSession();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"] = m_UserSession;
                }
            return m_UserSession;
        }
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult || myUserSession == null || !myUserSession.IsAuthenticated || myUserSession.AdvertiserId == 0)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                    { "client", filterContext.RouteData.Values["client"] },
                    { "controller", "Account" },
                    { "action", "Login" },
                    { "returnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am working from within a larger project so we get our session from a higher namespace. The issue it will redirect fine if I am logged out or if I do not have authorization (redirect to the area login page) but it seems if I idle (session times out??) it will still act like I am authorized but will not have any credentials attached to the session. So it still thinks I am validly logged in but I am not. Am I forgetting something in my filter check? The cookie is no longer valid but its like the user is still able to access the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code stems from the fact that ASP.NET MVC 3 might cache instances of action filters. It is one of the [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#RTM-BC):

> In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC, action filters are create per
>   request except in a few cases. This behavior was never a guaranteed
>   behavior but merely an implementation detail and the contract for
>   filters was to consider them stateless. In ASP.NET MVC 3, filters are
>   cached more aggressively. Therefore, any custom action filters which
>   improperly store instance state might be broken.

And since you have cached the `m_UserSession` private field into the action filter, it's never null and your test doesn't pass.

So, here's how you could proceed:

```
public class PortalAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var userSession = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserSession"] as WebSiteSession;
        if (userSession == null || !userSession.IsAuthenticated || userSession.AdvertiserId == 0)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                { "client", filterContext.RouteData.Values["client"] },
                { "controller", "Account" },
                { "action", "Login" },
                { "returnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As far as creating and storing a new `WebSiteSession` instance into the session, that's not something that an authorization filter should do. It's something that you should do inside your `Login` action upon successful authentication. The authorization filter is there to only check if the user is authorized to access the action.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has clarified the issue for me. I did not know it cached that.